# Push notification icon in Cordova Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I'm using [Phonegap Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/) and when a push notification is shown in the notification area, the icon is just a white square. I would like it to show `star.png` instead. I tried following [the documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#images) as follows:

I put `star.png` in `www/images`, and added the following lines to `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="www/images/star.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/star.png" />
  <resource-file src="www/images/star.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/star.png" />
  <resource-file src="www/images/star.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/star.png" />
  <resource-file src="www/images/star.png" target="res/drawable-ldpi/star.png" />
</platform>
```

(I understand that I should use different resolutions, but I'm just trying to get it working now.)

Then when I initialize the plugin, I use:

```
let push = PushNotification.init({
    android: { senderID: globalData.firebaseSenderID, icon: 'star.png', iconColor: 'blue' },
    ios: {}
});
```

I also tried `icon: 'star'`. 
However the white square persists. How can I get this to work?

Using cordova@8.0.0 & cordova-android@6.4.0.

Comment: Can you verify if the `star.png` file has been correctly copied to `platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/star.png` during build? If yes then `icon: 'star'` should be able to correctly pull up the png file. Also you also need a default asset defined at `<resource-file src="www/images/star.png" target="res/drawable/star.png" />`

Comment: @JamesWong How can I verify this?

Comment: @JamesWong I worked it out, by examining the apk as a zip file. star.png is there.

Comment: @wezten Did you checked this - "With Android now greatly using Material design since 5.0 (Lollipop), push notification icons are forced to be monochromatic - this can be difficult to diagnose, as a lot of icons just show as a white square if not properly designed." What I feel is, may be star.png is not designed as per - https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html# resulting in just a white square

Comment: @Gandhi yes, my star is white on transparent. I made a pure android project with push notifications using this star, and it was fine.

Comment: can you provide the star image?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? If so please tag the right solution as I am also stuck on this

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem with this plugin and the default notification icon (white square). It seems like that `icon` property in the `init()` function was only for GCM (Plugin version 1.x). I found a solution to set the icon in the push payload (sent from server). Unfortunately I was not able to change the payload, as it is not our service in this application.

But fortunately firebase has also its own push-icon setting (default: white square icon) which can be replaced with a metadata tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

## Solution

Try this solution by adding the following `metadata` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml File located at `platforms/android/app/src/main/`:

```
<application>
    <!-- ... -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/star"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</application>
```

## Automation - hook

Run your android application and check if there appears your expected icon. If you're successful you could now extend your project by a cordova hook like we did. For example the following OSX bash script is always adding the above line to the AndroidManifest:

```
sed -i '' "s|</application>|<meta-data android:name=\"com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon\" android:resource=\"@drawable/star\"/></application>|1" platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: Hi, I like your *Automation-hook* fix. How about: do we need </application> on the next line ELSE it will potentially break xml semantic structure.

Answer (score 2):

For Cordova 8, I've set my `config.xml` file as follow:

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/notification/icon-mdpi.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/notification.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/notification/icon-hdpi.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/notification.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/notification/icon-xhdpi.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/notification.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/notification/icon-xxhdpi.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/notification.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/notification/icon-xxxhdpi.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/notification.png" />
```

Then I placed the icons in `resources/android/notification/` with these resolutions:

```
resources/android/notification/icon-mdpi.png     (24 × 24)
resources/android/notification/icon-hdpi.png     (36 × 36)
resources/android/notification/icon-xhdpi.png    (48 × 48)
resources/android/notification/icon-xxhdpi.png   (72 × 72)
resources/android/notification/icon-xxxhdpi.png  (96 × 96)
```

Afterwards just used when schedulelling the notifications as a property:

```
smallIcon: 'res://notification',
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the section in the documentation

> Where icon is the name of an `.png` image file in the Android `res/drawable` folder. For example: platforms/android/res/drawable/phonegap.png Writing a hook to describe how to copy an image to the Android res/drawable folder is out of scope for this README but there is an excellent tutorial that you can copy.`.  You can see this article for more details http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/

It clearly says you need in the `drawable` folder, which you don't have.

Comment: I do have - the `resource-file` elements I showed in my question should copy the images there. See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#resource-file.

Comment: I thought that that means it has to be in the relevant drawable folder, dependent on the resolution. Anyway, I added it to /drawable too and it didn't help.